# Using a custom Angular filter in a programmatically defined ng-table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, ngtable

So I have a table that is programmatically created and I want to apply a custom filter to only one of the fields.  I've created a plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/57rEPEYNylisoHyBysp4

So by applying the filter to the Age column, the table would return:

```
Name    Age
Enos    I'm a number greater than 30: 34
Moroni  I'm a number greater than 30: 50
Jacob   I'm a number less than 30: 27
Nephi   I'm a number less than 30: 29
Enos    I'm a number greater than 30: 34
Tiancum I'm a number greater than 30: 43
Jacob   I'm a number less than 30: 27
Nephi   I'm a number less than 30: 29
Tiancum I'm a number greater than 30: 43
Tiancum I'm a number greater than 30: 43
```

I've tried:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns | filter:{ age: numCheck }" ng-show="column.visible" sortable="column.field">
                {{user[column.field]}}
</td>
```

Among other things in the HTML.  I've also tried changing the getData function in the controller to no avail.

Is it possible to do this?

Best Regards,
Julie

**EDIT**
So I created this plunkr which is closer to what I want to do in real life (based on Explosion's answer below):

http://plnkr.co/edit/pynm57tlQK53bCKbQjht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`| filter` uses the *filter* filter, which is something different.  Instead, you want to apply the filter you created to the string you are displaying:

```
{{user[column.field] | numCheck}}
```

Of course you will need to do an additional check on whether you actually want to apply the filter or not.  There are a lot of ways to do this, but with the way you currently have everything set up I think the simplest would just be to check whether the value passed to `numCheck` is a number or not.

Comment: Okay, so I had gotten that far and was thinking I could specify the field somehow.    But I have figured out how to do what I want, so thanks Explosion!!